# what does {:02d} mean in Python

Tags: python, string, format

it's very hard to find information about `{:}` online
I saw some code below:

```
def dateformat(date):
    day, month, year=date.split('/')
    return "{:4d}{:02d}{:02d}".format(int(year),int(month),int(day))
```

I kinda of know it is filling leading `0` in the format, but I don't know what do `'02'` and `'d'` in `{:02d}` do?

Comment: You are looking for the [`str.format()` documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.format).

Comment: Check out [pyformat.info](https://pyformat.info/#number) for documentation on format strings. There's probably a bunch of other resources.

Comment: Re: `{:}`, you don't need the colon any more if there is no formatting to be done, as in `'hello {}'.format("world")`

Comment: You can learn everything about Python string formatting in this cookbook - https://mkaz.tech/python-string-format.html

Answer (score 39):

You are looking for the [`str.format()` documentation](https://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#str.format). Specifically, the `02d` part is documented in the [*Format Specification Mini-Language*](https://docs.python.org/library/string.html#formatspec).

`02d` formats an integer (`d`) to a field of minimum width 2 (`2`), with zero-padding on the left (leading `0`):

```
>>> 'No digits: {:02d}, 1 digit: {:02d}, 2: {:02d}, 3: {:02d}'.format(0, 7, 42, 151)
'No digits: 00, 1 digit: 07, 2: 42, 3: 151'
```

From the documentation:

> ```
> format_spec     ::=  [[fill]align][sign][z][#][0][width][grouping_option][.precision][type]
> ```
>
> *[...]*
>
> *width* is a decimal integer defining the minimum total field width, including any prefixes, separators, and other formatting characters. If not specified, then the field width will be determined by the content.
>
> When no explicit alignment is given, preceding the *width* field by a zero (`'0'`) character enables sign-aware zero-padding for numeric types. This is equivalent to a *fill* character of `'0'` with an *alignment* type of `'='`.
>
> *[...]*
>
> Finally, the *type* determines how the data should be presented. *[...]* The
> available integer presentation types are:
>
> *[...]*
>
> `'d'`
> Decimal Integer. Outputs the number in base 10.

The same formats apply to [formatted string literals (f-strings, `f"..."`)](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#f-strings).

Answer (score 1):

As for your information :

```
format(1, '02')
'01'

format(100, '02')
'100'
        
'{:02}'.format(1)
'01'

'{:02}'.format(100)
'100'
```

However, d in {:02d} means number in base 10