# How does.format() in this code work [pandas]

Tags: python, pandas

I am very much a beginner in pandas posting here for some help.
I was doing an assignment on Coursera, and after I did it I tried searching stack overflow to find more compact and faster codes. Stuff I saw on here I understood but when I did a search on Google I found some code on pastebin that looked too good to be true.

Here it is

```
def convert_housing_data_to_quarters():
    data = pd.read_csv('City_Zhvi_AllHomes.csv')
    towns = data[['State','RegionName']]
    for yr in range(2000,2017):
        for q in range(1,12,3):
            if yr == 2016 and q == 4:
                break
            m1 = '{}-{:02d}'.format(yr,q)
            m2 = '{}-{:02d}'.format(yr,q+1)
            m3 = '{}-{:02d}'.format(yr,q+2)
            quarter = '{}q{}'.format(yr,q)
            towns[quarter] = data[[m1,m2,m3]].mean(axis=1)
    return towns
```

The assignment was to read a .csv with data for each month and to make a dataframe with quarters from 2001q1 to the end each quarter has a value of the mean of the 3 months that make it up.
My solution was very normal and looking at code others wrote for this assignment it looked nearly similar.

The code linked up works for everything except that it named the columns as 20xxq1,q4,q7 and q10 instead of q1,2,3,4.
I don't understand how the code in the 2nd for loop works.

What does this syntax mean `'{}-{:02d}'`? I don't get this at all but it seems extremely powerful. I would love to know how to use it in the future. I saw the pandas documentation, it says you can use a dict as parameters for .format() but I really can't understand how its working here.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

`range(1,12,3)` gives the following result: `1, 4, 7, 10`. It just iterates through the values from `1` to `12` with a step `3`. If I understood it correctly, this code just outputs the quarters according to its first month. So, for example, the first quarter starts with the `first` month, then goes `forth` month and so on.

`'{}-{:02d}'.format(value1, value2)` just puts whatever values you put in `format()` inside those curly brackets. There is now a better way for formatting strings: `f'{value1}--{value2}'`.

`{:02d}` just prints numbers with a width of two (here is a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36543804/what-does-02d-mean-in-python))

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

`'{}-{:02d}'.format(yr,q)` is a string formating. It returns a combination of `yr` and `q` based on respective values. Since there is no index in the `{}` curly bracket, `yr` belongs to the first and `q` belongs to the second curly bracket. The second part after `:` is the format selected. `02d` means there will be two digits, with zero-padding if possible.

For more info about string formating, you can refer to [this link](https://pyformat.info/)